# Jira, Scriptrunner - getCurrentUser in Project Automation

Tags: groovy, automation, jira

I'm trying to send the currently logged-in user in a Post-Request to a REST-Endpoint when the issue is assigned. I set up a project automation with a ScriptRunner Script.
According to several sources (see below) the following should do the magic.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
def user = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser()
```

This snippet works, but it's always my user, that is sent. Doesn't matter if I'm logged in or my colleague. What am I missing?
The same problem occurs when I use the built-in field currentUser.

Sources:

- https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-to-get-current-user-in-jira-application/qaq-p/818002
- https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/5.2.1/jira/recipes/behaviours/scripted-conditions.html
- https://innovalog.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/JMWE/pages/138353228/Getting+the+current+user+-+Groovy

Comment: how do you send your request? have you tried a simple `return(user.toString())`?

Comment: What is your application scenario exactly? The getLoggedInUser() function should return the user who is currently logged in and viewing the Jira app on your computer, rather than the user who is currently online and viewing the Jira app on any other computers.

Comment: If your colleague views the Jira app on their own computer with their own Jira account, they will see their own name when running the getLoggedInUser() script.